# Index path of all list elements

Tags: r

**How to get index path of all list elements?**

```
tree <- list(1:6,b=list(a=20:23,b=28),c=c("a","b"))
```

How to get addressing information from existing list tree for all leaves?
Returned value in form of list of vectors, like below.

```
ret <- list(leaf1=c(1,1), .... ,leaf7=c(2,1,1), .... ,leaf13=c(3,2))
# tree[[c(2,1,1)]] should return 20 then.
# so the leaf7 value is indexing vector for tree$b$a[1] in another notation.
# so the tree$b$a[1] is same as tree[[ret$leaf7]]
# and so the object ret is then sort of a map of list "tree"
```

Comment: Your question is too terse. I don't understand it.

Comment: @Roland I would like to add more info, but I am not sure what detail to add. Can you hint me what you do not understand?

Comment: @Roland I supllied a bit more - the hashed comments

Comment: `breadth first search` and `depth first search` algorithms for graphs exploration are what you want. Use the fact that `length(1)!=1` and `length("a")` to detect the leaves to exit the recursive condition.

Comment: @Math, thank you for directing me to the theory sources, It will help as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your basic depth first search. The Map/unlist combo is to keep the result list flat, and thus the leaf level result of the else clause has to be wrapped in a list. The `idx` holds the current index into the structure and `acc` is the accumulated indices of the leaves.

```
index.leaves <- function(root) {
  walk <- function(node,idx,acc) {
    if(length(node)>1) {
      r<-Map(function(child,i) walk(child,c(idx,i),acc),node,seq_along(node))
      unlist(r,recursive=FALSE)
    }
    else {
      list(c(acc,idx))
    }
  }
  walk(root,NULL,c())
}
```

With the sample data

```
str(index.leaves(tree))
```

```
List of 13
 $     : num [1:2] 1 1
 $     : num [1:2] 1 2
 $     : num [1:2] 1 3
 $     : num [1:2] 1 4
 $     : num [1:2] 1 5
 $     : num [1:2] 1 6
 $ b.a1: num [1:3] 2 1 1
 $ b.a2: num [1:3] 2 1 2
 $ b.a3: num [1:3] 2 1 3
 $ b.a4: num [1:3] 2 1 4
 $ b.b : num [1:2] 2 2
 $ c.a : num [1:2] 3 1
 $ c.b : num [1:2] 3 2
```

Comment: It was not easy to decide which one to accept. Both yours and Talipovs answers are interesting. Thanks again.

Comment: I think that test if(length(node)>1) is not very robust and does not fit all cases,  better to use if(typeof(node) == "list" | length(node)>1) instead. I have tested the function on much larger real world case tree and that longer test fits better.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of recursive approaches, which use a different way to flatten the result list:

*Approach 1*. Depth first search; once we reach the bottom, save the result into an upper-level variable `L`.

```
nametree <- function(X) {
  L <- NULL

  rec <- function(X, prefix = NULL) {
    if( length(X) == 1 ) {L <<- c(L,list(prefix)); return()}    
    sapply(seq_along(X), function(i) rec(X[[i]], c(prefix,i)))
  }

  rec(X)
  L
}
```

*Approach 2*. Depth first search; vectors with indices are saved via `return`. In this case, the result is a nested list, so it should be flattened, which is achieved by the `rapply/unlist/split` combination.

```
nametree2 <- function(X) {

  rec <- function(X, prefix = NULL) {
    if( length(X) == 1 ) return(prefix)    
    lapply(seq_along(X), function(i) rec(X[[i]], c(prefix,i)))
  }

  z <- rec(X)

  # Convert nested list into a simple list  
  z2 <- rapply(z,length)
  split(unlist(z),rep(seq_along(z2),z2))
}

z <- nametree(tree)
z2 <- nametree2(tree)
```

Both approaches return the same result, which can be used to index the original `tree` list:

```
> tree[[z[[7]]]]
[1] 20
> tree[[z2[[7]]]]
[1] 20
```