# Recursive Array Resolution in R - Depth Search

Tags: arrays, r, recursion

I have an array `arr` of IDs, that form a tree

```
ID    CHILD 
11       12
11       13
12       14
12       16
13       17
13       18
18       19
```

and I need a recursive function, which tells me the maximal depth of any given ID.

Something along the lines of

```
res<-function(element,
              arr,
              depth)
{
X<-arr[which(arr[,"ID"]==element),"CHILD"]
  if(length(X)==0) return(depth)
  for (e in X){
    depth<-depth+1
    res(element=e,
        arr=arr,
        depth=depth)
  }
}
```

This however carries the depth counter over to the next child and increases it (I believe)..

I found [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28346569/index-path-of-all-list-elements/28349346#28349346), however I am working with arrays and need the depth, not the index. My brain can't get round it anymore.

## Update - Solution

Thank you Dominic Comtois for the graph-based solution.
In the meantime, my brain decided to come up with a solution, similar to what I posted originally also incorporating the width as the number of lowest level elements in the tree, and it looks like:

```
glob_max_depth<-0
glob_max_width<-0

res<-function(element,
              arr,
              depth
              ){
    X<-arr[which(arr[,"ID"]==element),"CHILD"]
    for (e in X){
      res(element=e,
      arr=arr,
      depth=depth+1
      )
    }
    if(depth>glob_max_depth){
      glob_max_depth<<-depth
    } 
    if(length(X)==0){
      glob_max_width<<-glob_max_width+1 
    } 
  return(glob_max_depth)
}
```

Hopefully this helps future readers!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find recursing in R pretty painful. I recently worked (played, rather) with a [boggler solutioner](https://github.com/dcomtois/Boggler) using the `igraph`package and had to find "paths" within the graph, which is similar to what you're doing. It's not the same as looking solely for the longest path but it gives you more info along the way and I find graphs nice to work with because of the plotting ability.

Anyhow, see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28609703/boggle-cheat-erm-solutioning-with-graphs-in-r) if you're interested to go that route. To build the graph, you would use something like this (I substracted 10 to your ID's and CHILD's to work well with igraph):

```
library(igraph)
el <- matrix(data = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,8,2,3,4,6,7,8,9), ncol = 2)
g <- graph.edgelist(el, directed=TRUE)
plot(g)
```

Then, you could find paths of different lengths (here, 3 and 4) using this code:

```
getPaths <- function(v, g, L = 4) {
  paths <- list()

  recurse <- function(g, v, path = NULL) {
    path <- c(v, path)

    if (length(path) >= L) {
      paths[[length(paths) + 1]] <<- rev(path)
    } else {
      for (i in neighbors(g, v)) {
        if (!(i %in% path)) recurse(g, i, path)
      }
    }
  }
  recurse(g, v)
  return(paths)
}

paths <- list()
for(L in 3:4) {
  paths[[as.character(L)]] <- getPaths(1,g,L=L)
}
```

Happy [re]cursing!

Comment: Thanks so much! I was actually also looking to plot the resolved structure, I will use this.